# How can I disable CPU C2 and C3 states options?

Tags: dell, acpi

I have a DELL XPS 13 9333. As you can read here, it produces an annoying coil whine under some circumstances:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19538215.aspx

Someone suggested that the noise can be related to the CPU (Intel CORE i7) Cx states.
A workaround, under WIN8.1, is to disable states C2 and C3 trough the system registry:
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/292915-30-high-pitched-noise-coming-area#4294909

Do you know how can I disable C2 and C3 states under Ubuntu 12.04, so that I can give the workaround a try?